# How can I sign-extend a 5-bit value?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I have a unsigned integer (32 bit), in which I've stored an n-bit signed number (2's complement, so -16 ≤ x < 16, and the resultant unsigned value is in the range 0-15).

How can I transform this efficiently into a signed interpretation using the two's complement?

A short example to clarify what I mean:

```
int numUnsigned = 15; // Store a 4-bit value 0b1111
int numSigned = ???; // Convert to 4-bit signed value using two's complement
// Now numSigned should be -1, since 0b1111 == -1
```

I've been messing with the bits all morning but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: How about just extending the MSB (4th) till the bit 32? This should give you the signed representation of the 4th bit num.

Comment: It is a bit unclear where you get `n` from.

Comment: @Caleb I know that it is not the 2's complementary. I just misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AlexLop. The more I read it, the more I think you had the right idea. The question could use some clarification.

Comment: @Caleb The comment in the second line of the code is a little confusing... (@Boris)

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the "duplicate"

Comment: Agree with @harold, this question is not a duplicate and the answer(s) are also not duplicates because of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need a sign extension and not 2's complementary (at least according to your comment in the second line of code).

If I am correct, you can do the following (Let's assume you have N digits, 0 < N < 32):

```
unsigned msb_mask = 1 << (N-1); // setup a mask for most significant bit
numSigned = numUnsigned;
if ((numSigned & msb_mask) != 0) // check if the MSB is '1'
{
    numSigned |= ~(msb_mask-1); // extend the MSB
}
```

Maybe I misunderstood your question... If so then just ignore my answer.

**EDIT**

Suggested by @harold :

```
numSigned = (numUnsigned^msb_mask)-msb_mask ;
```

Comment: You can do this much simpler, but I can't answer anymore

Comment: @Boris `(x ^ 8) - 8` that's all you need

Comment: @harold can you write the simpler way here in comment?

Comment: That works because if the sign is set, then the xor resets it and then the subtract borrows through to the top, no matter how bit ints are. If the sign was unset, then the xor sets it and the subtract resets it again. (you can steal this thing if you want, @AlexLop.)

Comment: @harold I added your solution. Thanks.